# Node-Webkit and Three.js animation stop and hangs out in the page like a snapshot

Tags: three.js, node-webkit

My little experiment with node-webkit and three.js contains; two page;

- index.html ( contain one button to open wayfinder.html )
- wayfinder.html ( three.js animation code and a button ( named 'go' ) to back index.html )

If I use back button to return index.html, animation stops and but it hangs in the screen. Even index.html loaded ( I mean dom elements ), I can only see this stopped animation.

This looks like a node-webkit issue but i did not understand the problem exactly.

[*source code*](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/17279887/Kiosk.zip)

Comment: can you provide the full code so I can see it here?

Comment: I edit initial post, if you click ( wayfinder ) in index.html, it takes you wayfinder.html , basicly three.js loads a obj file and display it. Once model file loaded, if you click go button in wayfinder.html, hopefully you will see what I mean :)

Comment: discussion moved to https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues/452